# Why provides the jquery promise a faster chained animation than the common callback chaining

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

Both animations should have the same speed but it is not!

The jquery promise is that quicker that I can even measure it with my eyes ;-)

Why is that? Technically they do the same and this is chaining jquery functions.

```
 $.when( $('#a1').fadeOut() )
 .done( $('#a2').fadeIn() );


    vs.


$('#a1').fadeOut(function () {
    $('#a2').fadeIn(function () {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$.when( $('#a1').fadeOut() ).done(function() { $('#a2').fadeIn() });
```

Notice I added the `function() {}` around the `fadeIn()`. Not having that extra part causes the code to execute `fadeIn()` instead of passing the function as a parameter to the `done()` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxBTa/

Comment: Note that `$.when()` is not strictly necessary in this case. Personally, I would prefer `$('#a1').fadeOut().promise().done(function() { $('#a2').fadeIn() });` though it is a matter of choice.